# Python Cannot return the final value

Tags: python, math, return

I have stuck with this assignment.
I tried to do different combination with my code to get the return but failed. 
The question asks find radiation exposure within a period of time by using recursion.

Problem: I can get all the calculations correctly [I checked it using online python executor] but when the process comes to the final return, the result is `None`. I don't know why my code can't return the final calculation result. I wish: some guru out there can give me some clues thanks.

```
global totalExposure
totalExposure=0 

def f(x):
    import math
    return 10*math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

def radiationExposure(start, stop, step):
    time=(stop-start)
    newStart=start+step

    if(time!=0):
        radiationExposure(newStart, stop, step) 
        global totalExposure
        totalExposure+=radiation   
        radiation=f(start)*step
    else:
        return totalExposure
```

Test case 1:

```
>>> radiationExposure(0, 5, 1)
39.10318784326239
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As other mentioned, your if statement had no return.  It seems you forgot the  return in the if clause. There's one in the else but none in the if.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you forgot the  `return` in the `if` clause. There's one in the `else` but none in the `if.`

Answer (score 3):

@furas' code made iterative instead of recursive:

```
def radiationExposure2(start, stop, step):

    totalExposure = 0
    time = stop - start
    newStart = start + step
    oldStart = start

    while time > 0:
       totalExposure += f(oldStart)*step

       time = stop - newStart
       oldStart = newStart
       newStart += step

    return totalExposure
```

Converted to a for-loop:

```
def radiationExposure3(start, stop, step):

    totalExposure = 0
    for time in range(start, stop, step):
       totalExposure += f(time) * step

    return totalExposure
```

Using a generator expression:

```
def radiationExposure4(start, stop, step):
    return sum(f(time) * step for time in range(start, stop, step))
```

Answer (score 2):

As Paulo mentioned, your `if` statement had no return. Plus, you were referencing the variable `radiation` before it was assigned. A few tweaks and I am able to get it working.

```
global totalExposure
totalExposure = 0 

def f(x):
    import math
    return 10 * math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

def radiationExposure(start, stop, step):

    time = (stop-start)
    newStart = start+step

    if(time!=0):
        radiationExposure(newStart, stop, step) 
        global totalExposure
        radiation = f(start) * step
        totalExposure += radiation
        return totalExposure
    else:
        return totalExposure

rad = radiationExposure(0, 5, 1)
# rad = 39.1031878433
```

Answer (score 2):

Cleaner version without `global`

```
import math

def f(x):
    return 10*math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

def radiationExposure(start, stop, step):

    totalExposure = 0
    time = stop - start
    newStart = start + step

    if time > 0:
       totalExposure = radiationExposure(newStart, stop, step) 
       totalExposure += f(start)*step

    return totalExposure

rad = radiationExposure(0, 5, 1)

# rad = 39.1031878432624
```

Comment: Thanks. It's succinct.